# Calling a block though runtime, anything similar to NSInvocation?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime, nsinvocation

I have block of unknown type (as `id`) and array of arguments that need to passed into that block. Arguments may be objects or numbers/structs boxed as NSNumber/NSValue. Block may also return an object, number or struct. This is a library code, and types of arguments are not known beforehand.

Assuming that I can can dynamically read signature from the block descriptor, is there a way to construct something like an NSInvocation to call a block?

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly this works:

```
CGAffineTransform (^block)(id x, int y, CGSize z) = ^(id x, int y, CGSize z){
    NSLog(@"%@,%d,%@", x, y, NSStringFromCGSize(z));
    CGAffineTransform t = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    return t;
};

NSMethodSignature* sign = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:block_signature(block3)];
NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sign];
[invocation setTarget:block3];
void* x = (__bridge void*)@"Foo";
int y = 42;
CGSize z = { 320, 480 };
[invocation setArgument:&x atIndex:1];
[invocation setArgument:&y atIndex:2];
[invocation setArgument:&z atIndex:3];
[invocation invoke];
CGAffineTransform t;
[invocation getReturnValue:&t];
```

But on the other hand, this does not:

```
NSMethodSignature* sign = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(class)];
NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sign];
[invocation setTarget:block];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(class)];
[invocation invoke];
Class k = nil;
[invocation getReturnValue:&k];
```

AFAICS from the disassembly, implementation of the `[NSInvocation invoke]` checks for the class of the target, and if it is a block (subclass of `NSBlock`) then it always calls block function, regardless of the signature.

**Updated**: Reported as [rdar://25289979](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4940944436625408)

Answer (score 1):

There is! I have [a project on GitHub called WoolBlockInvocation](https://github.com/woolsweater/WoolBlockInvocation) which aims to mirror `NSInvocation`'s interface for use with Blocks.

It was actually created in response to [In Objective-C/C, can you write a function that combines 2 blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638666/in-objective-c-c-can-you-write-a-function-that-combines-2-blocks/17892240#17892240), so the constructor `+ (instancetype)invocationWithBlocks:(NSArray *)blocks;` assumes that you want to use it with multiple Blocks, but it works perfectly well with a single Block.

It figures out the encoding signature for you via the [`WSSBlockSignature` helper class](https://github.com/woolsweater/WoolBlockInvocation/blob/master/WoolBlockInvocation/WSSBlockSignature.h),* and gives you [`setArgument:atIndex:`](https://github.com/woolsweater/WoolBlockInvocation/blob/master/WoolBlockInvocation/WSSBlockInvocation.h#L67), [`getReturnValue:`](https://github.com/woolsweater/WoolBlockInvocation/blob/master/WoolBlockInvocation/WSSBlockInvocation.h#L85), [`invoke`](https://github.com/woolsweater/WoolBlockInvocation/blob/master/WoolBlockInvocation/WSSBlockInvocation.h#L100), and other methods just like `NSInvocation`'s.

Under the hood, it uses libffi to do the work. This requires a certain amount of prep to handle structs: [`CGSize`, `CGPoint`, and `CGRect` are accounted for](https://github.com/woolsweater/WoolBlockInvocation/blob/master/WoolBlockInvocation/WSSBlockInvocation.m#L338), and others can be added as needed.

(*Cave*: I originally tested it on OS X, x86_64. It hasn't been checked out on any other platform.)