# Get NSMethodSignature of a method block in a Protocol

Tags: c, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, swift-protocols

I'm trying to get the signature of a block in a Protocol method.

Here's a sample protocol:

```
@protocol ProtocolSample <NSObject>
- (void) doSomething: (void (^) (NSString *))a_block;
@end
```

I am able to get the signature of `doSomething` using the following:

```
Protocol *protocol_sample = @protocol(ProtocolSample);

unsigned int outCount;
struct objc_method_description *method_description_list = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(protocol_sample, YES, YES, &outCount);

struct objc_method_description method_description = method_description_list[0];

NSMethodSignature *signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:method_description.types];
```

The signature I get is: `v@:@?`

My goal is to get the signature of the `a_block`. I've tried many methods including the following:

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];

void *block;
[invocation getArgument:&block atIndex:2];
```

But `block` is always `NULL`.

How is it possible to get the signature of `a_block`?

Comment: A Block is an object, so `@` is correct. Have a look at my answers to similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36162832/603977 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892240/603977

Comment: @JoshCaswell Unfortunately, it does not work. I tried `WSSBlockInvocation * block_invocation = [WSSBlockInvocation invocationWithSignature:[WSSBlockSignature signatureForBlock:(__bridge id)(block)]];` where `block` is from the question text above. It gives an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because `block` is NULL.

Comment: Yes, you need an actual instance of the Block to use `signatureForBlock:`

Comment: @JoshCaswell How can I do that? I've been stuck on this issue for days :/

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you're trying to do this? It might help; there might be another way.

Comment: I have a list of protocols (100s) with methods that’d I’d like to get the signature for (instead of doing it manually). I know this functionality does exist but I’m not sure how to do it.

Comment: Instead of doing _what_ manually? What do you actually need the signature for?

Comment: Instead of manually looking at each method and determining its protocol. I can technically make a python script that reads the header file and determine the signature, but I’d like to do this natively in Obj-C. I just want to be able to do it for the sake of learning and maybe use it in the future if needed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell See my answer below. One function got the job done :)

Comment: Cool, nice find!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer: `const char *_protocol_getMethodTypeEncoding(Protocol *, SEL, BOOL isRequiredMethod, BOOL isInstanceMethod);`

The method will get you the full signature of any selector!

Answer (score 0):

There is also

```
extern const char* _Block_signature(id block);
```

which you can use for any arbitrary block object.

Comment: I tried using `_Block_signature` but it doesn't work. Do I have to import some framework to find it? I tried googling this function but I'm not finding anything, and Apple's doc turn up nothing.